# Store big number in java

Tags: android

I wan to create a funny incremental game in java but I don't know how to store data. I thought use a long but I'm not sure that it will be enough.
I know that big integer could works but I'm not sure thaht it's really efficient.

Comment: How big of a number are you talking about?

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried any of the solutions you describe and figured out they're not efficient enough for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use long or [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class, depending on how big number you want.
Check out this question/answer for a valid solution!

[What to do when you need to store a (very) large number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688460/what-to-do-when-you-need-to-store-a-very-large-number)

Comment: In case you notice that the question has already been answered in another post, please mark it as duplicate and provide the link to the answer.